# Как реализовать сравнение двух активити?

Tags: java, android

Реализовываю нижнее меню с треми иконками и, чтобы не копипастить код в 3 активити, реализовал фрагмент, но проблема в том, чтобы узнать, не нажал ли пользователь на уже открытое активити. То есть мне нужно что-то типо "getActivity != OpenedActivity". Как это реализовать ?

Comment: Если под нижним меню подразумевается что-то вроде `BottomNavigationView`, то Вам необходимо одно активити  и несколько фрагментов, которые будут отображаться по клику в `BottomNavigationView`. Связь между `нижнее меню с треми иконками` и `3 активити` непонятна.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для реализации нижнего меню используйте `BottomNavigationView`

У `BottomNavigationView` есть два слушателя:

- `BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener`
- `BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`

В случае, если вы выберите уже выбранный элемент нижнего меню, сработает первый срушатель, иначе второй слушатель.